# Частичное обновление при переходе на другую страницу с изменением url

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, html

Например есть страница index1.html, содержащая 2 diva, есть ссылка, направляющая на другую страницу index2.html, нужно чтобы содержимое страницы index2.html отобразилось во втором dive страницы index1.html, естественно полная перезагрузка страницы не должна происходить, и должен меняться url-адрес на index2.html (читал что такое возможно по средствам html 5 histori ну и ajax естественно). Если не трудно, то можно примерчик простой ?!

Answer (score 1):

По моему это просто кэш, + ЧПУ (ибо же mod_rewrite).

Comment: подробнее можно и пример желательно!

Comment: http://code-shark.net/post/12/sozdanie_chpu_v_PHP, я могу быть не прав на счет ответа, в html5 может дей-но какая-то своя фича для этого есть, напр. github интересно использует когда по репозиторию бродишь.

Comment: Человек спрашивает про AJAX обновление части страницы, а не про ЧПУ.

Comment: мне кажется он все-равно к тому прийдет рано или поздно, а что аякс уже ссылки в браузере разве менять может? Ну тогда Local Storage это называется (в плане html5). Мне честно говоря самому интересно.